# NSButton with title in different columns

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton, nsbuttoncell

I am doing a MacOs application and I would like to have a NSButton like this:

```
    --------------------------
    | text1            text2 |
    --------------------------
```

I have been thinking and I don't find a solution to have both labels in the same button.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about making a View and add two buttons on it?

Comment: What do you mean with "in different columns"? Do you have  an NSTableView object with multiple columns?

Comment: I want to have text1 and text2, in two different columns but embedded in a NSButton.